# Blade components with array names not showing "old" values

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and have run into a problem.

I have a single page which collects information about a `Parent` and a `Child` (two different models). To allow for separate validation, and because the models share some fields, I've created a form that uses `parent[...]` and `child[...]` arrays to keep the fields separate. In the controller, I can then validate and create parents, linked to children etc. The controller is working, the validation is working - validated data is being added to the database...

However, I'm running into problems with the validation errors.

I have the following (example) Blade component to display a textarea.

components/form/textarea.blade.php:

```
<x-form.field>
    <x-form.label name="{{ $name }}">{{ $slot }}</x-form.label>

    <textarea name="{{ $name }}"
             id="{{ $name }}"
    >{{ old($name) ?? $slot) }}</textarea>
    <x-form.error name="{{ $name }}"/>
</x-form.field>
```

This works find for components with plain names such as:

`<x-form.textarea name="notes"/>`

However, I'm running into problems when this is part of an array:

`<x-form.textarea name="child[notes]"/>`

In this instance the `old` values and any validation errors don't show. They *do* show when I hard-code the name to "dot" notation: `child.notes`.

Is there a method I can use to convert the `name` dynamically so that the form gets the correct array syntax and the `old` and `@error` get a dotted version thereof?

Or should I be using a different approach altogether?

**Edit:**

Using the example:

```
<x-form.textarea name="child[notes]">Child Notes</x-form.textarea>
```

I imagine that it would expand to the first level at least, as follows:

```
<x-form.field>
    <x-form.label name="child[notes]">Child Notes</x-form.label>

    <textarea name="child[notes]"
             id="child[notes]"
    >{{ old("child[notes]") ?? "") }}</textarea>
    <x-form.error name="child[notes]"/>
</x-form.field>
```

However, I *want* it to expand like this:

```
<x-form.field>
    <x-form.label name="child[notes]">Child Notes</x-form.label>

    <textarea name="child[notes]"
             id="child[notes]"
    >{{ old("child.notes") ?? "") }}</textarea>
    <x-form.error name="child.notes"/>
</x-form.field>
```